# Open one view in Landscape from table view did select row by default in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode5, tableview, landscape

I have tried all the options in stack over flow, some answers are not effective and some are not explained properly.I have a table view and once did select row called, i am pushing it to the new view controller. Now at this juncture i want that new view controller on landscape.All my views are portrait, i want this single new view controller to be in Landscape. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change UIInterfaceOrientation for only one UIViewController in app iOS (SOLVED!)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357156/change-uiinterfaceorientation-for-only-one-uiviewcontroller-in-app-ios-solved)

Comment: And also: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 0):

Add the following method in your Landscape View controller

```
-(NSUInterger)supportedInterfaceOrientation
{
  return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscape;
}
```

Also din't forget to set your Orientation property under Attribute Inspector in Storyboards.